# CUDA profiled achieved occupany very low; how to diagnose?

Tags: cuda

When I run the profiler against my code, part of the output is:

```
Limiting Factor
Achieved Occupancy:  0.02 ( Theoretical Occupancy:  0.67 )
IPC:  1.00 ( Maximum IPC:  4 )
```

Achieved occupancy of 0.02 seems horribly low.  Is it possible that this is due to missing .csv files from the profile run?  It complains about:

```
Program run #18 completed.
Read profiler output file for context #0, run #1, Number of rows=6
Error : Error in profiler data file '/.../temp_compute_profiler_1_0.csv' at line number 1. No column found
Error in reading profiler output:
Application : "/.../bin/python".
Profiler data file '/.../temp_compute_profiler_2_0.csv' for application run 2 not found.
Read profiler output file for context #0, run #4, Number of rows=6
```

My blocks are 32*4*1, the grid is 25*100, and testing has shown that 32 registers provides the best performance (even though that results in spilling).

If the 0.02 number is correct, how can I go about debugging what's going on?  I've already tried moving likely candidates to shared and/or constant memory, experimenting with **launch_bounds**, moving data into textures, etc.

Edit: if more data from a profile run will be helpful, just let me know and I can provide it.  Thanks for reading.

Edit 2: requested data.

```
IPC: 1.00
Maximum IPC: 4
Divergent branches(%): 6.44
Control flow divergence(%): 96.88
Replayed Instructions(%): -0.00
Global memory replay(%): 10.27
Local memory replays(%): 5.45
Shared bank conflict replay(%): 0.00
Shared memory bank conflict per shared memory instruction(%): 0.00

L1 cache read throughput(GB/s): 197.17
L1 cache global hit ratio (%): 51.23
Texture cache memory throughput(GB/s): 0.00
Texture cache hit rate(%): 0.00
L2 cache texture memory read throughput(GB/s): 0.00
L2 cache global memory read throughput(GB/s): 9.80
L2 cache global memory write throughput(GB/s): 6.80
L2 cache global memory throughput(GB/s): 16.60
Local memory bus traffic(%): 206.07
Peak global memory throughput(GB/s): 128.26

The following derived statistic(s) cannot be computed as required counters are not available: 
Kernel requested global memory read throughput(GB/s) 
Kernel requested global memory write throughput(GB/s) 
Global memory excess load(%) 
Global memory excess store(%) 
Achieved global memory read throughput(GB/s) 
Achieved global memory write throughput(GB/s)
```

Solution(s):

The issue with missing data was due to a too-low timeout value; certain early runs of the data would time out and the data not be written (and those error messages would get lost in the spam of later runs).

The 0.02 achieved occupancy was due to `active_warps` and `active_cycles` (and potentially other values as well) hitting maxint (2**32-1).  Reducing the size of the input to the profiled script caused much more sane values to come out (including better/more realistic IPC and branching stats).

Comment: Would be interesting to see how much time is spent reading/writing data, as well as some kernel code to see what is going on. Not sure about the missing csv files, if they might be a problem. EDIT: Other interesting output from the profiler would be diverged branches and uncoalesced and coalesced memory read/writes.

Comment: Is that the data you're looking for?  The values don't seem unreasonable to me; certainly not like something at 0.02 occupancy.

Comment: To bad the counters for the global read/write throughput is not available. Kind of weird, but would have helped. Can you give some kernel code as well? I have no idea what you kernel does, or how much work it involves. I think you don't have a lot of data though, so might be to little work for the GPU if the algorithm doesn't involve a lot of work.

Comment: What tool or command line do you use to get the "Achieved Occupancy"?

Comment: I'd be shocked if any of the tools that I was using 7.5 years ago still worked on modern cuda cards/drivers. I'd start with https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-systems and see if that meets your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hardware counters used by the Visual Profiler, Parallel Nsight, and the CUDA command line profiler are 32-bit counters and will overflow in 2^32 / shaderclock seconds (~5s). Some of the counters will overflow quicker than this. If you see values of MAX_INT or if your duration is in seconds then you are likely to see incorrect results in the tools.

I recommend splitting your kernel launch into 2 or more launches for profiling such that the duration of the launch is less than 1-2 seconds. In your case you have a Theoretical Occupancy of 67% (32 warps/SM) and a block size of 4 warps. When dividing work you want to make sure that each SM is fully loaded and preferably receives multiple waves of blocks. For each launch try launching NumSMs * MaxBlocksPerSM * 10 Blocks. For example, if you have a GTX560 which has 8 SMs and your reported configuration above you would break the single launch of 2500 blocks into 4 launches of 640, 640, 640, and 580.

Improved support for handling overflows should be in a future version of the tools.

Comment: Thanks for the update / clarification.  Good to know about the ~5sec rule.  :)  I've switched this to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretical occupancy is the maximum number of warps you can execute on a a SM divided by the device limit. Theoretical occupancy can be lower than the device limit based upon the kernels use of threads per block, registers per thread, or shared memory per block.

Achieved occupancy is the measure of `(active_warps / active_cyles) / max_warps_per_sm`.

An achieved occupancy of .02 implies that only 1 warps is active on the SM. Given a launch of 10000 warps (2500 blocks * 128 threads / WARP_SIZE) this can only happen if you have extremely divergent code where all warps except for 1 immediately exit and 1 warp runs for a very long time. Also it is highly unlikely that you could achieve an IPC of 1 with this achieved occupancy so I suspect an error in the reported value.

If you would like help diagnosing the problem I would suggest you

1. post your device information
2. verify that you launched `<<<{25,100,1}, {128, 4, 1}>>>`
3. post your code

If you cannot post your code I would recommend capturing the counters active_cycles and active_warps and calculate achieved occupancy as

```
(active_warps / active_cycles) / 48
```

Given that you have errors in your profiler log it is possible that the results are invalid.

I believe from the output you are using an older version of the Visual Profiler. You may want to consider updating to version 4.1 which improves both collection of PM counters as well as will help provide hints on how to improve your code.

Comment: active_warps and active_cycles are both 4294967295 for me, AKA 2**32-1.  Looks like I hit maxint.  :/  1.0 / 48 ~= 0.02  I'll accept this once I get the full details written up.  Thanks!

Comment: To make sure you are having a good experience with the tools, it would be great if you could try the 4.1 release and let us know if the results are better!

Comment: We weren't planning on touching the CUDA setup until Kepler.  :/  Will there be a CUDA update to coincide with Kepler?  And if so, is there still time to get changes in?  (I'd assume that ship has long-sailed, but maybe not ;)

Comment: I'm talking about the visual profiler, not changing your code. Just want to make sure we find and fix any bugs in the tools that we can.

Comment: Right, we weren't planning on changing our toolkit version, but I went ahead and installed the 4.1 toolkit on a dev box.  Now it's saying that the driver is out of date; we're using 280.13-0ubuntu6, which seems to be the latest on ubuntu 11.10.  The "Getting started" doc on linux wasn't updated for 4.1, and a few minutes of searching hasn't given me an obvious answer for what version I need.  I'm sure it's out there, but it's not staring me in the face, which would be handy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like (a big part of) your issue here is:

`Control flow divergence(%): 96.88`

It sounds like 96.88 percent of the time, threads are not running the same instruction at the same time.  The GPU can only really run the threads in parallel when each thread in a warp is running the same instruction at the same time.  Things like `if-else` statements can cause some threads of a given warp to enter the `if`, and some threads to enter the `else`, causing divergence.  What happens then is the GPU switches back and forth between executing each set of threads, causing each execution cycle to have a less than optimal occupancy.

To improve this, try to make sure that threads that will execute together in a warp (32 at a time in all NVIDIA cards today... I think) will all take the same path through the kernel code.  Sometimes sorting the input data so that like data gets processed together works.  Beyond that, add a barrier in strategic places in the kernel code can help.  If threads of a warp are forced to diverge, a barrier will make sure that, after they reach common code again, the wait for each other to get there and then resume executing with full occupancy (for that warp).  Just beware that a barrier **must** be hit by all threads, or you will cause a deadlock.

I can't promise this is your whole answer, but it seems to be a big problem for your code given the numbers listed in your question.

Comment: Yeah. Seems right. Another tip is to allow all threads to execute the same instructions, even though you really don't need to. If the thread don't need the data it just computed you can throw them away. Main thing is: Avoid branching if it's possible (If you can't, then maybe your problem suits the CPU better?)

Comment: This may be a performance problem, but it has nothing to do with the occupancy problem, unless, as Greg pointed out, most of the warps are exiting far earlier than one long running warp.